# OpenCV camshift algorithm

Tags: image-processing, opencv, video-processing

I got a lab report to make in an image processing course in my university, and I was asked a question about the OpenCV camshift algorithm (for video tracking):

*the camshift algorithm works on the hue component of the HSV color space.  I need to explain why working on this component should give better results than working in the RGB color space.*

I must admit that I'm not familiar with OpenCV at all, and basically I'm leaning all the color model theory specifically for this course, so please consider that...thanks.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/18311/why-use-hue-channel-of-hsv-for-mean-shift-tracking/

Comment: "should give better results"... what kind of results are these -- what is the application?

Comment: video tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SR who posted here http://answers.opencv.org/question/18311/why-use-hue-channel-of-hsv-for-mean-shift-tracking/ the H channel in HSV

> "... is not influenced by the image brightness and saturation. You get the "pure" color disregarding the actual lighting (which might change over time)."